# When hovering on link tag, add :after class to its parent

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I have a banner that includes a `ul` with various `li`'s including `a` tags. The below snippet illustrates the behaviour that when the user hovers on the `a`, an underline is added at the bottom of the banner using `:after` and a slightly "hacky" specific bottom pixel value.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.banner {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightpink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 25px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -65px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0%;
  content: '';
  color: transparent;
  background: black;
  height: 3px;
}

ul li a:hover::after,
ul li a:active::after {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The below is an updated approach, with the attempt to move away from specifying specific bottom values (as the banner will not always be the same height). I've now made the `li` the full height of its parent element and have tried to add the `:after` class to the `li`, so that the need for `bottom: -65px` for example would not be required.

I'm avoiding leaving it as it is currently and just making the `a` full height, as this would mean hovering above the `a` would activate the underlined hover state.

So ideally, the `a` tag remains its current height (just the height of the text), but when hovered on, the `:after` styles are added to its parent `li`. Is this possible?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}


.banner {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightpink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  gap: 25px;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0%;
  content: '';
  color: transparent;
  background: black;
  height: 3px;
}

ul li:hover::after,
ul li:active::after {
  transition: all 0.2s;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No, this is not possible. CSS does not work that way. *In CSS child descendant or following element can be selected, but not the parent or preceding element*